# pe:ckEditor is not working since version 12.0.5

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I just upgraded PrimeFaces Extensions to version 12.0.5 and noticed that the CKEditor is no longer available. Is it a bug? Has it been renamed or moved? I can't remember seeing anything about it in the migration guides.

What can I do to make `pe:ckEditor` work with PFE 12.0.5+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately CKEditor has asked us to remove the component due to legal reasons (license mismatch). See https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/1106

Since PrimeFaces Extensions 12.0.6, [SunEditor](https://github.com/JiHong88/suneditor) (which is MIT licensed) is available. You can use that as a replacement for CKEditor. See: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/1110